# Wide cracks across asphalt road

Tags: crack, asphalt

Location: US California desert

What would cause multiple 1 to 1.5 inch wide cracks, averaging 25 ft apart in asphalt roadway? (not regularly spaced, though)

Comment: Are the cracks across the roadway, along the roadway or both?

Comment: @Lee Sam  Strictly across

Comment: This happens everywhere when there is no traffic.

Answer (score 2):

Normal expansion and contraction. That's what asphalt does. In Minnesota those cracks show up within two years of road resurfacing due to our weather extremes. It is exacerbated by age, where the asphalt has dried and doesn't stretch as well.

Comment: Would this be worse if the asphalt was poured in the heat of the summer and then shrank in the winter? And then settles in to the smaller size?

Comment: I have often wondered about that myself, but I can't say for sure.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the cracks appeared between asphalt pours, i.e., instead of paving one lane, then the other, they paved this road edge-to-edge by the truckload. The successive pours did not blend/bond seamlessly because the new hot pour didn't seam well with the previous cooler pour.